# Access to a folder mount from a docker container

Tags: docker, mount

I'm trying to mount a filesystem inside a docker volume.

The Docker created is mounted this way:

```
docker run -v /tmp:/tmp -d -t ubuntu
```

Now on the host I create a folder inside tmp to run the cifs mount:

```
mkdir /tmp/mnt
mount -t cifs -o username=XX,password=XX,domain=XX //hostname/share /tmp/mnt
```

- If I ls from the host, `/tmp/mnt` is correctly mounted and contains files
- If I ls from the host, `/tmp/mnt` remains empty

Now if I start a new container *after* `/tmp/mnt` is mounted, then `/tmp/mnt` is also correctly mounted inside the container.

Is this a normal behavior?

Is there something I can do to access folders mounted after the container creation?

Comment: Is the sentence after your second bullet point missing a word?

Comment: I reworded the sentence, hope this is clearer

Comment: [`docker volume create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) can be run with basically arbitrary mount(8) options; would this be a better way to access the remote filesystem?

Comment: In fact I have a lot of running containers which mounted /tmp. And when mounting a new subfolder inside /tmp, I expect to access it from all the containers.